# jQuery UI Dialog - Uncaught TypeError in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am attempting to implement a jQuery UI dialog in Wordpress 4.5.3, but it only works about half the time. The rest of the time I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).dialog is not a function  lwr_jquery_dialog.js(2)
```

I have enqueued the scripts as follows, and verified they load in the correct order on the page:

```
function enqueue_jquery_dialog() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog', false, array('jquery','jquery-ui-core'), 
        false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script('lwr_dialog', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
        '/js/lwr_jquery_dialog.js', array('jquery-ui-dialog') );        
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery_dialog' );
```

In lwr_jquery_dialog.js I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#dialog').dialog({
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
    });
});
```

And here's the actual dialog function in functions.php

```
function add_jquery_dialog() {
    ?>  
    <div id="dialog" title="Today Only">
            DIALOG TEXT HERE
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_jquery_dialog');
```

Comment: Half the time sounds like a script is not in the right order, and just so happens to either be cached the second time or loads just-in-time that you don't notice it being an issue the first time. Check the order of your scripts and ensure jquery-UI is loaded after the main jquery library. if it's not that, stay open-minded about it when you look at the code again - if it happens to be something like this let me know and I'll make an answer of it!

Comment: Have you tried changing the priority of the add_action?

Comment: Try changing jQuery to $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 1**: You're missing `jquery-ui-dialog` script. Try this instead:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
  $theme_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

  wp_enqueue_script('lwr-jquery-dialog', $theme_uri . '/js/lwr_jquery_dialog.js',
['jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-dialog'], false, true);
}, 10, 0);
```

---

Since you're using `false` as value of source file, the dependencies are not enqueued correctly. See `$src` param from [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function for more info.

Try this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
  $theme_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

  wp_enqueue_script('lwr-jquery-dialog', $theme_uri . '/js/lwr_jquery_dialog.js',
['jquery-core', 'jquery-ui-core'], false, true);
}, 10, 0);
```

Comment: Even when it fails, I've verified in the html source that the files are loading in the correct order. I tried this, but with no additional luck.

Comment: @dpruth I have made a test and updated the answer. Hope it works this time.

Comment: My script above includes jquery-ui-dialog. But I did update the wp_enqueue_script function with your suggestion (taking out "FALSE") and it seems to be working now. Thanks!